# Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 Experience

Tags: roots, radicals

I built a spreadsheet that accurately determines a character's level by looking at the experience.

You can find a chart of this here: https://www.ign.com/wikis/dungeons-and-dragons/Level_and_XP_progression

The formula I actually use is (for Google Sheets) `=INT(0.02*(SQRT((B2+125)*5)-25)+1)` ; The `int()` 's purpose is to round the value down to the nearest integer because there are no non-interger levels in Dungeons & Dragons. And `B2` is the current Character's Experience.

Anyway I simplified the formula (ignoring `int()`) to: `=((5*B2+625)^0.5+25)/50`
$$\frac{\sqrt{5\times\text{current experience}+625}+25}{50}$$

**I was wondering if there is a more eloquent or easy to write the formula than what I have in order to calculate a players level based on a given amount of experience?**

Comment: If $x:=B2/125$ then level $=(1+\sqrt{x+1})/2$.

Comment: Given the specific structure of the formula there exists no real simplification. Every way to write it will include summation and multiplication/division both inside an outside of the root.

Comment: Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) as you continue posting here. For example: `$$\frac{\sqrt{5\times\text{current experience}+625}+25}{50}$$`

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown I used your suggestion -- although I think that the colored version was better.

Comment: @Xzila use `\color{orange}{whatever text}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems unlikely. The level breaks are just the triangular numbers $\times 1000$, i.e., $500 n(n-1)$, and what you’ve got in your question is the result of applying the quadratic formula to this. Any other expression for this value is also likely to involve radicals, too. One thing you could do to make it a bit simpler is to absorb that factor of $1000$ into the XP term: $$\left\lfloor {1+\sqrt{\text{xp}/125+1}\over2}\right\rfloor.$$

Then again, you could instead simply replicate the level progression table in a couple of hidden columns of your spreadsheet and use Excel’s `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: It took me a second (my algebra is rusty) to coerce my formula into the one you provided to prove to myself that they were the same. The one you provided does have "nice numbers" and it is easier to read. Thank you!